# How do I recover tab / session information from Chrome / Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser-tabs

If I can no longer run chrome itself, How can I recover tab information from files in the chrome profile directory?

Comment: This is a self-answered question for the solution I found, but I'll make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ccl-ssns](https://github.com/cclgroupltd/ccl-ssns) (before [on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/ccl-ssns/)) with the 'Last Tab' and 'Last Session' files in

- **Windows 7, 8.1, and 10**: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
- **Mac OS X**: `Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`
- **Linux**: `/home/$USER/.config/google-chrome/Default`

The Tabs listed in the output HTML with index '0' are the last tabs open.

Comment: Have they moved these files into the `Sessions` folder by chance?

Answer (score 12):

### Attention to passerbys!

### The two answers here are both outdated as of July 2021.

The Current Session|Tabs files are no longer used.
But you will find in the `Default/Sessions/` folder lies the last two sessions and tabs files.

Answer (score 1):

The files that restored my session from the backup files where:

`.config/google-chrome/Default/Current\ Session`

And

`.config/google-chrome/Default/Current\ Tabs`

Just copy the files to `/home/username/.config/google-chrome/Default`